# How can I shutdown / not start a spring app if a flag was not provided?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I inject a flag using `@Value("${FOO}")` and I don't want my spring app start at all if it wasn't provided (i.e., `FOO` is a mandatory flag).

Here's my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

and I inject `FOO` into one of the services.

How can I do it?

Comment: how are you providing the value? is this running in local tomcat or pivotal?

Comment: @KalpeshSoni local tomcat

Comment: using --dFOO="someValue"

Comment: and if you dont do it, it should fail, thats default behavior

Comment: based on the paramter value

public static void main(String[] args) {
if(some condition donot meet){
  System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args)));
}
SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
 
 }

Comment: @KalpeshSoni do u mean it'll fail by default? What about the optional flags though?

Answer (score 1):

Resolving of properties placeholders is controlled by [PlaceholderConfigurerSupport](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.html). And by default it should throw an exception if it was unable to resolve a placeholder:

> If a configurer cannot resolve a placeholder, a *BeanDefinitionStoreException* will be thrown.

However, when I tried to use a `@Value` with a property that didn't exist, it threw an exception, but it didn't stop the JVM.

What you can do to force it to stop is to implement `InitializingBean` and check the property in the `afterPropertiesSet()` method:

```
@Service
public class YourService implements InitializingBean {

    @Value("${foo:#{null}}") // set the default value to null
    private String foo;

    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        if (foo == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("foo flag must be provided");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inject Foo you need to start your application. This may not be the proper way but this will work. What you can do is to create a bean like this. In the bean you can add your own condition to shutdown the app. This will prevent the start of the app while the bean gets created.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleApplication {

    @Value("${foo}")
    private String foo;

    @Bean
    public String preventStart() {
        if("no".equals(foo) ) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return "started";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SpringBoot runners can you used for doing this before the application starts up.
you can find examples here 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_runners.htm